# Excel PowerPivot Help: Totals is not summing the Absolute Value correctly

Tags: powerpivot

I know `PowerPivot` is not programming, but I wanted to see if I could get help or a recommendation on how to get the total rows to correctly calculate the sum of Absolute Values at a higher aggregation level that the detailed data in a `PowerPivot` data model.

Here is my example:  This is detailed data format.  There are 2 hierarchies:

```
1.  Product Group\Product Family\**Material**    '3 columns'
2.  Region\**Plant**\SalesMgr\Employee\Customer   '5 columns'
```

Hierarchy represents 8 columns in my data model

All data in the data model is at the lowest level (i.e. Material/Customer).  However I want to calculate Forecast Accuracy at Material/Plant Level (a higher aggregation level).

```
DataModel Column9: Sales  'Sales at the detailed Material/Customer'
DataModel Column10: Forecast   'Forecast at the detailed Material/Customer'
Calculated Column11:  AbsoluteError = ABS(Forecast - Sales)  'calced at Mat/Cust'

PowerPivot DAX formulas/measures, shortened for simplicity
TotalSales:=SUM(Sales)
TotalAbsError:=SUM(AbsoluteError)
MAPE:= TotalAbsError/TotalSales
ForecastAccuracy:= 1 - MAPE (Mean Absolute Percentage Error)
```

This calculates the data correctly at the Material/Plant level when I create my Pivot Table.   However the Total values in the Pivot Table are incorrect.

For example, the Total of AbsError is the Sum of 20 rows of Material/Customer Combinations.   I need the Total of only the 5 Material/Plant Combinations.  The 20 rows of detailed Material/Customer data aggregates up to only 5 rows of Material/Plant Combinations.

I have a sample spreadsheet I can share.  Thanks Dimitry for updating the question!

I would like to post the spreadsheet / powerpivot so that the StackOverflow community can see it.  I assume I have to post a link.  I will start trying to figure out how.

Thanks 
David